# Termination due to memory pressure and memory leak in system library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

When I run my app using Instruments, I face the following issues before the app eventually crashes:

- Allocations: There is a constant increase in total bytes up to 1-2GB. This increase is seen even before any leak is detected.
- Leaks: There are multiple leaks. On looking at the Call tree, I find they are in the system libraries:

  - with symbol names, malloc_zone_malloc and malloc in libsystem_malloc.dylib
  - the bytes used column shows 192 Bytes, 100%

When I run it in xcode, I get a 'terminated due to memory pressure' error.

My questions are-

Is filing a bug report with apple the only solution since the leaks are in system libraries?

Are the leaks, the only reason behind the crash; given that only 192 Bytes are leaked and memory usage increases even before leaks?

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting memory allocation and leaks it's almost always a good idea to exclude system libraries and look for your code only. It's very unlikely that you have discovered such basic and easy to find bug in core libraries and nobody took care of this before.

The facts that leaks are indicated in `malloc` doesn't mean anything. All memory allocations will go through mallocs at the end. You need to look for bugs in your code first.

Comment: Given that malloc means the bugs could be anywhere in the code, is there any better starting point to locate the bugs other than commenting out graphics intensive portions of the code?

Comment: You don't need to comment out stuff. First try to run it in profiler.